# Oracle SQL using variable in Select or For-Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql

I need to verify data across several tables.  In essence i want to write a loop for the below statement with all of the fields in a given table.

```
sql> select fld1, count(*)
from table1
group by fld1
;
```

I'm thinking that I need to create at least 2 variables. The first variable would be prompted to provide the table name.

The second var would be something based on the result of :

```
select column_name from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name = table_variable
```

Should I also create a temp table and select into that?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can store the values in the temporary table.

1.Fetch Table Name & Column Name put in Variable Var_Table_name,Var_Col

```
select Var_Col, count(*) into Var1,Var2 from Var_Table group by fld1 ;
```

for all the tables columns .You can create a temporary table and insert the values as mentioned below and store in the temp table .

1.Var_Table_name

2.Var_Col

3.Var1

4.Var2

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL does not prompt.  On the other hand SQL*Plus will prompt for substitution variables.  See following example.

```
MPOWEL01> @stack
MPOWEL01>
MPOWEL01> select table_name, column_name from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name = upper('&tbl_nm')
  2  order by column_name;
Enter value for tbl_nm: marktest
old   1: select table_name, column_name from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name = upper('&tbl_nm')
new   1: select table_name, column_name from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name = upper('marktest')

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
MARKTEST                       FLD1
MARKTEST                       FLD2
MARKTEST                       FLD3
MARKTEST                       FLD4

MPOWEL01>
```

`set verify off` will eliminate the substitution message line from the output.

In PL/SQL you either need to SELECT INTO variables or use a cursor.

I think you might just be able to use SQL to generate the SELECT statements you want to run, but what exactly do you mean by 'verify data'?  Verify how?  Using what standard?